# Javascript Object Literal - calling

Tags: javascript, object, literals

What's the way of calling the property within the method of the specific object - here's an example:

```
var myObject ={
    firstProperty : 0,
    secondProperty : 0,
    myMethod : function(){
         // this is where I'm not quite sure
          $(this).firstProperty = 1;
    }
}
```

I'm sure **$(this).firstProperty = 1** is wrong - but how would I call the property within the method of the object (self, this etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do it is to avoid using `this` altogether:

```
var myObject ={
    firstProperty : 0,
    secondProperty : 0,
    myMethod : function(){
          myObject.firstProperty = 1;
    }
}
```

The reason is that the meaning of `this` changes depending on the context. For example, with the code in your question, what happens when you do `document.getElementById('somelement').onclick = myObject.myMethod` ? The answer is that `firstProperty` will instead be set on `somelement`. The same goes for this:

```
var f = myObject.myMethod;
f(); // firstProperty is now set on the window object!
console.log(window.firstProperty); // Logs 1 to the console
```

So be warned :)

Comment: I do see your point but it is rather obscure, not sure that I've ever seen someone (or needed to myself) use an instantiated object's member method as DOM event handler...

Comment: So what you're suggesting is to use the object name even withing its own methods?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the way of calling the property within the method of the specific object

very confusing....

I think another way to ask this is

> How do I reference a property of an object, from within one of its methods?

If this is a accurate way to explain what you are looking for then...

In this case `this` will reference `myObject`.

so `this.firstProperty` should work.

Comment: `this.firstProperty` will only work as long as `myMethod` is called on `myObject`. See my answer below.